# Не работает простой калькулятор у новичка на Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
def Add(num1, num2)
    res = num1 + num2
    puts res
end

def Minus(num1, num2)
    res = num1 - num2
    puts res
end

def Multiply(num1, num2)
    res = num1 * num2
    puts res
end

def Division(num1, num2)
    res = num1 / num2
    puts res
end

puts "Введите знак математической операции"
puts "Для выхода введите пустую строку"

user_input = gets.encode("UTF-8").chomp


if(user_input == "+")
    puts "Введите первое число"
    num1 = gets
    puts "Введите второе число"
    num2 = gets
    Add(num1, num2)

elsif(user_input == "-")
    puts "Введите первое число"
    num1 = gets
    puts "Введите второе число"
    num2 = gets
    Minus(num1, num2)

elsif(user_input == "*")
    puts "Введите первое число"
    num1 = gets
    puts "Введите второе число"
    num2 = gets
    Multiply(num1, num2)

elsif(user_input == "/")
    puts "Введите первое число"
    num1 = gets
    puts "Введите второе число"
    num2 = gets
    Division(num1, num2)

elsif(user_input != "+" || user_input != "-" || user_input == "*" || user_input == "/")
    puts "Error!"

else(user_input = "")
    abort

end
```

Пишет в консоли:

```
C:/rubytut/MyPrograms/Calc.rb:18:in `Division': undefined method `/'
for "2\n":String (NoMethodError)from C:/rubytut/MyPrograms/Calc.rb:54:in `<main>'.
```

Comment: Возможно, вы удивитесь, но [`gets` (он же `Kernel#gets`)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) возвращает `nil` или строку (`String`). Ничто из этого делить нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Приведи к целому `num1` и `num2`, перед тем как с ними что-то делать.

```
num1 = num1.to_i
num2 = num1.to_i
```